# IndexOutOfBoundsException in JSF 2 based application after upgrate to Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, jsf-2.2

I have simple Spring 4.1.6, Spring Security, JSF 2.2 based application running on WildFly 9 that works with Spring Security 3.2.x just fine.

After upgrade to Spring Security 4.0.x I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
09:18:00,123 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-5) java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:166)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1611)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:379)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:366)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:589)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:150)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:654)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:82)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:198)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:195)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.forward(RequestWrapper.java:139)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.java:71)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:253)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can you please give me a piece of advice what I should change so my application will work with Spring Security 4 properly.

I created simple reproducer where you can check the source code.

https://github.com/trepel/dragons

Maybe it has something to do with JSF's PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING, because if I disable it in web.xml, the exception has gone. But the buttons ('All Dragons' and 'Dragons with age' stops working as well and also

```
AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

is thrown when trying to add new dragon.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: what did you do... Only upgraded the jars or also some config changes?

Comment: yes, just change value in _ssec_ property in `pom.xml` from "4.0.1.RELEASE" to "3.2.7.RELEASE" and the example should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Spring Security 4.x the CSRF protection is enabled by default - unlike Spring Security 3.2.x where it is disabled by default - and this causes the exception.

See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-3033 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. Spring security + JSF2:

Whenever there is a "h:form" inside "sec:authorize", there is an IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="Member">
    <h:form>
     ....
    </h:form>
</sec:authorize>
```

I fixed it by adding csrf token:

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="Member">
    <h:form>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
         ....
    </h:form>
</sec:authorize>
```